# BIND DNS: Exclude specific sudonmain to wildcard Record

Tags: dns, bind, wildcards, subdomain, exclude

I don't know if i am in the good category or even the good forum. But like i saw many tutorials on Ubuntu and other linux version and their fixs didn't solve my problem, i imagined that there is some custom ways to do in Centos for my problem. OK i explain

My config: Centos 7.5, Bind9

I setup a DNS server with bind on centos 7 and now the DNS server works as well. But in a zone "exemple.com" and create A records with wilcard and specific records for some other subdomain. for example

```
                      IN NS ns1.example.com.
*.example.com.  IN A 192.168.5.1
ns1.example.com IN A 192.168.5.1
foo.example.com. IN A  192.168.5.2
```

In many topics i saw that wildcard only resolves DNS query for all request that has not been defined so foo.example.com must return the ip 192.168.5.2. To verify this i use the command `dig @localhost foo.example.com` on the same server and it still return me 192.168.5.1 ..  i flush dns with `rndc flush` ...normally dig command make query directly on my local DNS  avoiding propagation issue i think, I also try with a client machine with nslookup ...foo.example.com that was 48 hrs ago and still continue but no change foo.example.com don't point 192.168.5.2

Did someone already get this problem? How have you fixed that?

Comment: Have you checked the Bind9 logs to make sure it successfully loaded the new zone?

Comment: What results do you get from `dig example.com AXFR @localhost`?

Comment: "To verify this i use the command dig @localhost foo.example.com on the same server and it still return me 192.168.5.1 "  This is not possible, it would be a very broken nameservers. It is clear from specifications that the wildcard record is used ONLY if no direct records (matching fullly) is found.

Comment: "foo.example.com that was 48 hrs ago and still continue but no change foo.example.com don't point 192.168.5.2"  this means you probably forgot to update the serial of the SOA record when changing your zone, and hence your nameserver does not see it changed.

Comment: @Patrick Mevzek thanks you was right, i need to update the serial in SOA record. after i restart the service and when i use the dig to the subdomain the correct ip just show as result.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You should post and answer so that OP might be able to accept it.